# Assigning a zero to a vector in Verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

In Verilog, I have a vector element defined as:

```
logic [ width_x - 1 : 0 ] x ;
```

I want to assign the value 0 to x.
Can I always safely use :

```
assign x = 0 ;
```

Or should I use ?

```
assign x = { width_x { 1'b0 } } ;
```

Comment: I think the first one is enough and safe. But we're told to use the second form to reduce messages produced by lint tools and to ensure 100% safety.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SystemVerilog has the bit fill literals `'0`, `'1`, `'x`, and `'z`.  This means fill a vector with a digit to whatever width is required by the context. (In a self-determined context, it is just a single bit) You should write:

```
assign x = '0;
```

Comment: And what about Verilog ?

Comment: For 0 values, I think it is save to use either code you have shown. But your lint tool might have other ideas.